# Stored Procedure produce data for a range of dates

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have this table:

```
PRJ_ID | START      | FINISH
xxxx   | 2015-01-01 | 2016-01-01
```

I have two separates date start_range and end_range.

I would like to produce the following output using a stored procedure in SQL Server 2008 for example with this parameters start_range=2015-02-01 and end_range=2016-08-01:

```
PRJ_ID |   DATE     | STATUS
xxxx   | 2015-02-01 | ACTIVE
xxxx   | 2015-03-01 | ACTIVE
xxxx   | 2015-04-01 | ACTIVE
xxxx   | 2015-05-01 | ACTIVE
.
.
.
xxxx   | 2016-08-01 | NOT ACTIVE
```

Where the DATE field should be the first day of the month for each month from the start_range to the end_range

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having this parameters `start_range=2015-02-01` and `end_range=2016-08-01`, we can generate a list of dates, recursively (see ;WITH cteDates).
This part could be replaced with a calendar table , if you have it.

```
DECLARE @dStart_Range AS DATE = '2015-02-01',
        @dEnd_Range AS DATE = '2016-08-01'

DECLARE @tPRJ AS TABLE
    (   
        PRJ_ID CHAR(4) NOT NULL,
        START DATE NOT NULL,
        FINISH DATE NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (PRJ_ID)
    );
INSERT INTO @tPRJ(PRJ_ID,START,FINISH)
VALUES('xxxx','2015-01-01','2016-01-01');


-- generate the list of dates
-- could be replaced by a calendar table if exists
;WITH cteDates
AS(
    SELECT @dStart_Range AS aDates
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(MONTH,1,aDates)
    FROM cteDates
    WHERE   
        aDates < @dEnd_Range
)
--SELECT * FROM cteDates

SELECT
    P.PRJ_ID AS [PRJ_ID],
    D.aDates AS [DATE],
    CASE WHEN P.START <= D.aDates AND P.FINISH>= D.aDates THEN 'ACTIVE'
         ELSE 'NOT ACTIVE' END AS [STATUS]
FROM    
    cteDates AS D
    CROSS JOIN  @tPRJ AS P
```

And the result is:

```
PRJ_ID DATE       STATUS
xxxx   2015-02-01 ACTIVE
xxxx   2015-03-01 ACTIVE
xxxx   2015-04-01 ACTIVE
xxxx   2015-05-01 ACTIVE
xxxx   2015-06-01 ACTIVE
xxxx   2015-07-01 ACTIVE
xxxx   2015-08-01 ACTIVE
xxxx   2015-09-01 ACTIVE
xxxx   2015-10-01 ACTIVE
xxxx   2015-11-01 ACTIVE
xxxx   2015-12-01 ACTIVE
xxxx   2016-01-01 ACTIVE
xxxx   2016-02-01 NOT ACTIVE
xxxx   2016-03-01 NOT ACTIVE
xxxx   2016-04-01 NOT ACTIVE
xxxx   2016-05-01 NOT ACTIVE
xxxx   2016-06-01 NOT ACTIVE
xxxx   2016-07-01 NOT ACTIVE
xxxx   2016-08-01 NOT ACTIVE
```

Comment: While this method works, I'd be very careful about the recursive CTE approach at scale. [I may have even done some testing to prove my point](http://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-3).